# Why won't the volume follow the hardware control in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

My iPad app uses AVAudioPlayer to play background music. When I want change the volume by adjusting the volume button (hardware) that rim of iPad, it still sound as loud as it was.

Why it that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the AudioSession category?

```
NSError* error = nil;

if ( ![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error] )
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
```